# VSCodeでLaTeXのエンジン切り替えを簡単に行う方法は？

Tags: vscode, latex

Windows環境にTeX LiveをインストールしてLaTeXを使用しています。
VSCodeの拡張機能LaTeX Workshopとlatexmkを使用してコンパイルを行っているのですがLaTeXのコンパイルエンジンを簡単に切り替える方法が見つかりません。

現状は以下のように`settings.json`を記述しています。

```js
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        // LuaLaTeX で書かれた文書のビルドレシピ
        {
          "name": "LuaLaTeX",
          "tools": [
            "Latexmk (LuaLaTeX)"
          ]
        },
        // XeLaTeX で書かれた文書のビルドレシピ
        {
          "name": "XeLaTeX",
          "tools": [
            "Latexmk (XeLaTeX)"
          ]
        },
        // LaTeX(upLaTeX) で書かれた文書のビルドレシピ
        {
          "name": "upLaTeX",
          "tools": [
            "Latexmk (upLaTeX)"
          ]
        },
        // LaTeX(pLaTeX) で書かれた文書のビルドレシピ
        {
          "name": "pLaTeX",
          "tools": [
            "Latexmk (pLaTeX)"
          ]
        },
    ],
```

LaTeX Workshopの設定のLatex-workshop › Latex › Recipe: Defaultというところでfirstと設定しているため、一番上のLuaLaTeXが普段は使用されるのですが、これをpLaTeXに切り替えたいときに簡単に切り替える方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

現状はこのrecipesの順番を入れ替えることで対応しているのですが少々面倒です。それとも設定のところに、以下のように書いてあることからfirstとlastUsedしか選択できないのでしょうか？

> Define which recipe is used by Latex-workshop: Build. It also applies to auto build. Recipes are referred to by their names as defined in Latex-workshop › Latex: Recipes. Note there are two particular values:
>
> - first means to use the first recipe in Latex-workshop › Latex: Recipes;
> - lastUsed means to use the last run recipe.

Comment: こちらの記事 [なるべくデフォルトのまま使いたい人へ](https://qiita.com/Yarakashi_Kikohshi/items/e9270af54569640fe80f) でタイトルはデフォルトのままが主題ですが、変更するにはどうすれば良いか等が記述されているらしいので、参考にしてみては？

Answer (score 1):

> 以下のように書いてあることからfirstとlastUsedしか選択できないのでしょうか？

よく読むと

> Recipes are referred to by their names as defined in Latex-workshop › Latex: Recipes.

と書いてあります。つまり、“Recipe: Default”の値としては`first`と`lastUsed`**以外に**「レシピの名前」も書けます。「レシピの名前」というのは`latex-workshop.latex.recipes`における`name`の値のことです。

つまり、質問者のsetting.jsonの場合だと、「pLaTeX」と入力すれば`pLaTeX`のレシピがデフォルトになります。